# How do I make the spacebar menu display nodes in the Node Editor?

Tags: interface, shortcut

(using Blender 2.79b)

Almost invariably, when I watch a video on Cycles material nodes, they have an ability to hit spacebar, then type the name of a node to add that node to the editor. For example, <kbd>Space</kbd>+`ramp` pops up a Color Ramp node. An example of this is shown below: [image: desired result]

When I try this, though, all I get is this:
[image: undesirable result]

Googling told me about a plugin called "Dynamic Context Menu," but that does not allow the desired type-and-select functionality.

To clarify, I can add nodes with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and hunting through the menus that way; I simply want to have this much more efficient way of accessing them.

Comment: There is keymapping which makes it possible, see https://gist.github.com/bitinn/22f6fefe026d8d9e83468864edb8f835#node-editor-specific. It is possible to grab only that functionality from the keymap as well if the rest is unconvinient (or just create one yourself as in the answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the node search by name is on default on the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>. However you can assign it any shortcut you want.

By default, you can access the search by pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > and then selecting *Search*. Your presented searchbar will show up and show the nodes as results.

[image: search for nodes]

(I consider it possible, that the makers of the tutorials you mention, simply pressed clicked the search option too fast for a frame to capture.)
If you wish to add an even more direct shortcut to this functionality, go to the User Preferences <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>. Scroll down to the Node Editor and add a new shortcut. Assign a key combination to it and enter `node.add_search` into the identifier field.

[image]